# is there any way to get high quality image after resize in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['quality']      = '99';
    $config['source_image'] = $img_path;
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] =TRUE;
    $config['width']  = 300;
    $config['height'] = 220;
    $config['new_image']='uploads/'. $this->upload->data('file');
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
```

I am using `image_library` in codeignter but they produce low quality image there is any way to get quality of image.
this is the output after resize.

[image]

Comment: do you have complete knowledge of CI?

Comment: yes i know please help me

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
function uploadimage()
{

       $image_upload_folder='**upload folder path**';
       $this->upload_config = array(
                    'upload_path' => $image_upload_folder,
                    'allowed_types' => 'png|jpg|jpeg|gif|GIF|PNG|JPEG|Jpeg|JPG',
                    'remove_space' => TRUE,
                    'encrypt_name' => TRUE,
            );

       $this->load->library('upload');
       $this->upload->initialize($this->upload_config);

       if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image')){
              return $group_image = '';
       }
       else{
              $data = $this->upload->data();

              $this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../uploads');//fetching path

              $config1 = array(
                      'source_image' => $data['full_path'], //get original image
                      'new_image' => $this->gallery_path.'/**thumb image path**', //save as new image //need to create thumbs first
                      'maintain_ratio' => true,
                      'width' => 600,
                      'height' => 600

                    );
             $this->load->library('image_lib', $config1); //load library
             $this->image_lib->resize(); //generating thumb

             return $group_image =  $data['file_name'];
           }
}
```

Comment: check using above function and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$image_data =   $this->upload->data();
    $configer =  array(
                        'image_library'   => 'gd2',
                         'source_image'    =>  $image_data['full_path'],
                        'maintain_ratio'  =>  TRUE,
                        'quality' => '40%'
                    );
                    $this->image_lib->clear();
                    $this->image_lib->initialize($configer);
                    $this->image_lib->resize();
```